# Are woman more Judging than men in the MBTI?

Tags: personality, gender, mbti

<sup>Since I lack of academic formation please be tolerant if I write something not correct.</sup>

As you know the Myers-Briggs Type Indicator (MBTI) test is based on 4 personality dimensions (E/I, S/N, T/F, J/P) each of which can assume two possible values (I think the name is trait) for a total of 16 clusters. <sup>[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers-Briggs_Type_Indicator#Cognitive_learning_styles)</sup>

There are gender differences with regard to a number of psychological variables (see for example [gender roles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_roles) and [wikipedia Sex differences in human psychology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_differences_in_human_psychology)). These differences may be due to education, culture, hormonal difference and so on.

According to the stereotype, many women are more judging than men.

Does any empirical evidence show that the prevalence of Judging is higher in women compared to men?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MBTI is widely used in applied contexts, such as for personnel selection. Nevertheless, it is hardly used in scientific research on personality because its theoretical basis questionable, because its validity is limited, and because its reliability is inferior to other established measures of personality (for a starting point to criticisms of the MBTI see McCrea & Costa, 1989 and [this earlier post](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/)). For these reasons it is unlikely that you will find reliable data on gender differences in the MBTI.

However, it has been shown that the MBTI traits overlap with those of the Big Five (the most widely adopted model of personality) and gender differences with regard to the Big Five have been studied extensively.

The MBTI **Judging** dimension and its Perceiving counterpart **overlap to a large extent with the Big Five trait [conscientiousness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscientiousness)** (e.g., Furnham, 1996, McCrea & Costa, 1989). This is not surprising if you look at how Judging vs. Perceiving and conscientiousness are measured:

**Judging vs. Perceiving** is [measured](http://www.myersbriggs.org/my-mbti-personality-type/mbti-basics/judging-or-perceiving.htm) by having people choose between sentence pairs such as

- "I like to have things decided." vs. "I like to stay open to respond to whatever happens."
- "I like to make lists of things to do." vs. "I appear to be loose and casual. I like to keep plans to a minimum."
- "I like to get my work done before playing." vs. "I like to approach work as play or mix work and play."
- "I plan work to avoid rushing just before a deadline." vs. "I am stimulated by an approaching deadline."

Conscientiousness is [measured](http://ipip.ori.org/newNEOKey.htm) by items such as

- "I get chores done right away."
- "I carry out my plans."
- "I stick to my chosen path."

Thus, there appears to be a clear semantic overlap between the two constructs.

Are there gender differences with regard to conscientiousness? According to a large scale meta analysis (with data from more than 23.000 participants from 26 nations, Costa et al. 2001), 1. there are far more personality differences within the genders than between genders 2. **for conscientiousness there doesn't seem to be a detectable gender difference**.

**References**

Costa Jr., P., Terracciano, A., & McCrae, R. R. (2001). Gender differences in personality traits across cultures: Robust and surprising findings. Journal of Personality and Social Psychology, 81, 322–331. doi:10.1037/0022-3514.81.2.322

Furnham, A. (1996). The big five versus the big four: the relationship between the Myers-Briggs Type Indicator (MBTI) and NEO-PI five factor model of personality. Personality and Individual Differences, 21, 303–307. doi:10.1016/0191-8869(96)00033-5

McCrae, R. R., & Costa, P. T. (1989). Reinterpreting the Myers-Briggs Type Indicator From the Perspective of the Five-Factor Model of Personality. Journal of Personality, 57, 17–40. doi:10.1111/j.1467-6494.1989.tb00759.x

Comment: Thanks.. even still I cannot understand completely.. why do they called "judging" which sounds like "to judge myself and someone else" the attitude to "get chores done right away"? If you want I can open a question on this point.. I can intuit why a judging attitude push to do homework but I wonder if there is a scientific explanation.

Comment: Difficult to tell. Probably, it's just somewhat weirdly named. See for yourself: http://www.myersbriggs.org/my-mbti-personality-type/mbti-basics/judging-or-perceiving.htm "Do not confuse Judging with judgmental, in its negative sense about people and events. They are not related. "

Comment: @MaríaAnt if you don't get things done, there will be a lot of judgement!

Answer (score 0):

According to the following document there is a prevalence of the Judging trait  most of women seems to be Judging.

> the stereotype that females prefer routines, plans and outlines is
>   largely justified; the majority fall into the judging category. It may
>   come as a surprise, however, that the majority of boys (about 52-58
>   percent) are judging types as well.

http://schreibendepot.wordpress.com/2007/02/23/mbti-and-gender-a-personality-divide/

However a stronger difference, correlated to gender, from MBTI is about other traits (dimension?).

The following picture, taken from this article is interesting:
[image]
http://www.statisticbrain.com/myers-briggs-statistics/

Comment: Wow, look at the TF slant among women, or the IE difference between women and men! JP pales in comparison. But since JP is about Action, you would see the effects of it far more. I know I have : )

Comment: @nocomprende The table isn't really informative. See here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9877/intuitive-explanation-of-mbti-test-and-its-gender-bias?lq=1

Comment: @MaríaAnt OK, but the most striking discrepancy in this particular table is still the TF difference between male and female. JP is a blip. Why would someone seize on that?