# Intuitive explanation of MBTI test and it's gender bias

Tags: personality, mbti

According to [this](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/6190/4425) data there is a small bias related to the gender and some traits of MBTI.

[image]

Is it scientifically possible to provide an explanation for these differences?

My intuitive definition of the judging trait could be: "A judging subject spends time trying to classify the reality into categories (i.e. ethical or not). A high percent of his automatic thought go in this direction. Thinking how the world should be instead of changing himself to get the maximum from the world he could be less adaptive."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the data in the table, it is not possible to tell whether there is a meaningful difference between men and women with regard to the Judging trait, because it does not state the size of the sample, the effect size, and whether the difference is statistically significant. All differences could be just random noise. In fact, the data may just as well be more supportive of the idea that gender does not make a difference here.

Because the MBTI does not hold up to scientific scrutiny (and is hardly used by academic personality researchers), it should be difficult to find reliable data on gender differences. However, because the Judging dimension overlaps with the Conscientiousness factor in the Big Five, one can look at gender comparisons there. There do not seem to be strong gender differences with regard to Conscientiousness (see [this earlier answer](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/6189/are-woman-more-judging-than-men-in-the-mbti/9884#9884)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you like to have a look, I've opened another question which is related to your answer here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9887/why-the-consciousness-from-big-five-and-judging-from-mbti-overlaps