# Why do some researcher still prefer Myers-Briggs Type Indicator over Five-Factor model?

Tags: measurement, personality

Big Five or Five-Factor model has 32 traits while Myers-Briggs Type Indicator has only 16. But inspite of this, there are still people who use MBTI over Big Five.

Comment: Please edit your interesting question with some references to what you have been reading about the Big Five and MBTI personality models. Researchers prefer different things for different reasons, so it is especially critical to know which researchers you are talking about. Remember that SE questions stick around long after we forget we ever asked them! 

Writing a thorough question will not only help you attract high-quality answers for your question, but will help other people with the same question for a long time afterwards (i.e., I still get rep on 1+ year old Q/As.).

Comment: I asked this question because, one( Idon't remember the source) I've read somewhere that Big Five is less "scientific" that MBTI and should not be used always.

Comment: I think the question has a very interesting core that many people would be interested in knowing (B5 vs. MBTI comes up often enough), but it is somewhat unclear and insufficiently researched. Maybe you could restate your question in terms of the relative validity of the Big Five and MBTI personality models, and give a quick summary of each for posterity's sake. Given a thorough question, I would be happy to give a review. You may also want to look at the related question http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/is-the-myer-briggs-type-indicator-mbti-a-reasonable-scientific-theory?rq=1

Comment: Thanks and sorry if my questions are "dumb". I've no formal education Psychology or Neuroscience. I'm just curious.

Comment: It's not dumb at all. If you're new to SE, the site is like a mix of Reddit and Wikipedia. People ask questions to the best of their ability, and other people help them shape those questions to fit the knowledge domain and site through comments and edits. We do ask that question authors put an appropriate amount of effort into their questions, though, both because the question should be useful to anyone who wants to know, and giving proper answers takes time.

Comment: Can not other's edit my question here, like for wikipedia?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22164/discussion-between-christian-hummeluhr-and-budhijeevi).

Comment: Personality researchers regard the MBTI as unscientific. See here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/is-the-myer-briggs-type-indicator-mbti-a-reasonable-scientific-theory?lq=1 or here: http://www.vox.com/2014/7/15/5881947/myers-briggs-personality-test-meaningless Some people in personnel selection still like it, but that may be a question of fashion rather than science.