# Testosterone in women vs. estrogen in men?

Tags: statistics, physical-attraction

It is [known](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17950291) that women with higher estrogen are more likely to find men with higher testosterone as more attractive. Positive feedback is also [known](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.yhbeh.2008.07.012).

*But are women with higher testosterone level are more likely to find men with higher estrogen level as more attractive? Are men with higher estrogen level are more likely to find women with high testosterone level as more attractive?*

Note, that higher testosterone does not immediately mean lower estrogen (so, first paragraph does not answer negatively) or vice versa. Some people can have both of these higher or lower than mean values (for their gender).

**References**

Roney, J. R., & Simmons, Z. L. (2008). Women's estradiol predicts preference for facial cues of men's testosterone. *Hormones and Behavior*, 53(1), 14-19.
DOI: [10.1016/j.yhbeh.2007.09.008](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.yhbeh.2007.09.008) PMID: [17950291](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17950291)

Welling, L. L., Jones, B. C., DeBruine, L. M., Smith, F. G., Feinberg, D. R., Little, A. C., & Al-Dujaili, E. A. (2008). Men report stronger attraction to femininity in women's faces when their testosterone levels are high. *Hormones and Behavior*, 54(5), 703-708.
DOI: [10.1016/j.yhbeh.2008.07.012](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.yhbeh.2008.07.012) PMID: [18755192](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18755192/)

Comment: Thank you @rus9384, and welcome to CogSci! +1 You can futher improve this by turning the references into [APA references](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/q/469/21) with DOI links. E.g. [see my edit here](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/18235/21).