# Why do we dream of unattainable wishes being satisfied in dreams?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, dreams

We want many things that we might never achieve or attain in real life. Often we dream, that we have these things.

What is the psychological function of this type of dream? How does the satisfaction inside a dream relate to the dissatisfaction in reality?

Comment: I'm not clear on your question. Are you asking about dreams in the sense of aspirations or as experiences while you sleep? Are you asking why people want what they can't have? Or something else?

Comment: Jeromy Anglim check out i have edited the question.

Comment: If you're saying that people tend to dream of attaining or having attained their goals (rather than failing at them, or being in the process of goal pursuit before attaining them), and then asking why...I'd say your premise needs questioning itself. What makes you think people don't dream of failure, or dream of pursuing unattained goals, or at least that people don't dream of these as often as they dream of attainment? In my own personal dream experience, failure seems a more prevalent theme, for better or worse...

Comment: @what: interesting edit. I think I like it! I'll upvote this version if it has Devgeet's approval.

Comment: Really Nick Stauner?

Comment: @NickStauner you should delete that comment it is too personally revealing.

Comment: Oh, please, tell me what it reveals! :P Just kidding; that would deserve its own question...if I thought it did, anyway. Blame my skepticism for failing to ask it! And @DevgeetPatel, I'm not sure what you're asking about, but in any case, yes, really :)

Comment: @NickStauner http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5526/is-dream-interpretation-reliable

Comment: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/643/4086! Some good answers here too, mostly supporting my skepticism.